# how to enter diacritic in input field with autofill

Tags: input, diacritics

Can anyone please tell me how to enter an S-cedille (Ş <- this one I pasted from word) in an inputfield in a form on a web page? In Word (for instance) I can press ALT and type 0350.

But how do I do that in a web form field? If I press ALT and type 0350 in this field I am typing in now, it shows up as  ^.

I can't find it anywhere, not even Google can tell me how to do it (or at least I can't find it).

[Added:]This filed I am using is a control with autofill from the database. I type a letter and the control shows all names starting with that letter. I can then pick one from the list. That is why i cannot use Ş (`&#350;`), as the control does not recognise it as a S-cedille.

Thanks a bunch

Comment: Supposing you're no Windoze: Type it in Word, copy it and paste it in the browser.

Comment: @Thomas Kilian that may be effective, but not very user friendly.

Comment: Looks like it is some exception - you can change ^ to S cedilla by javascript in that particular input, on keyup event, if you can assume no name starts with ^.

Comment: @n-dru Thank you for your reply. I don't think this is an exception, hovever. It works the same in the textarea of the question form in this forum. Changing ^ to S-cedilla through javascript sounds like a horrible hack to me. What should i do with other diacriticals in that case?

Comment: It depends on browser, operating system and web content (use of Java Script). So there is no general answer to your question (except what I commented above).

Comment: @ThomasKilian Thanks for mentioning this. Can you tell me where can i find info about what to use when? I would like to give some options to the user of the form. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry. Tuning web pages for the named constraints is a major source for headaches of many web programmers. Quite a number of web programmers have committed suicide due to the pure existence of IE4 to <whatever is current>.